# Workaround mapping between NetworkInfo and NetworkInterface

Tags: android, android-networking

I'm facing an issue that was reported in [this tracker issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14548) back in 2011 and would like to develop a suitable workaround. I would like to display all of an Android device's network interfaces to the user, as well as categorize them by their type and whether or not they are currently active. I'm targeting API 15 at minimum.

As far as I know, there are two ways to get network interface information:

1. Via the built-in Java `NetworkInterface` class using `NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()`. This will return `NetworkInterface` objects that contain information like the interface name, all IP addresses associated with the interface, etc. For my device (LG G3), I get interfaces like `lo`, `wlan0`, and `rmnet0`. This also returns information like the IP address, MTU, subnet mask, and broadcast address, which I need.
2. Via the Android API `ConnectivityManager` service using `aConnManager.getAllNetworkInfo()`. This returns about 20 `NetworkInfo` objects for my device, most are unused, but they include types `MOBILE`, `WIFI`, `BLUETOOTH`, etc. This doesn't include any network parameters like IP addresses, MTU, etc. as mentioned above.

The issue as explained in the tracker is that there's no built-in way to map the `NetworkInfo` to a `NetworkInterface` or vice-versa, and I would like to avoid using the interface name to map to the appropriate `NetworkInfo` if at all possible.

Since I have a hunch that's not possible, is there a list somewhere of all of the potential network interface names for most vendors? `rmnet[0-9]` seems common for devices with Qualcomm baseband processors, and `wlan[0-9]` for WiFi, etc.

In the worst case I suppose I could list the interface type as unknown if the interface name doesn't match any common templates. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Since API 21, you can use [`LinkProperties`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/LinkProperties.html) to get a [`NetworkInterface`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html) object out of a [`Network`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/Network.html) `network` object:

```
ConnectivityManager manager = getSystemService(ConnectivityManager.class);
LinkProperties prop = manager.getLinkProperties(network);    
NetworkInterface iface = NetworkInterface.getByName(prop.getInterfaceName());
```

However, although [`getAllNetworks()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getAllNetworks()) is supposed to replace [`getAllNetworkInfo()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getAllNetworkInfo()) (the former, introduced in API 21, has deprecated the latter in API 23), as of Android 6.0.1, it does not. `getAllNetworks()` **does not** list all networks (see [SO Q#33374766](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33374766)). Looks like a bug.

Alternatively, in order to inform the user about the status of all network connections, a set of callbacks may be registered for each transport type available in [NetworkCapabilities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkCapabilities.html) (*i.e.* `TRANSPORT_CELLULAR`, `TRANSPORT_WIFI`, `TRANSPORT_ETHERNET`, `TRANSPORT_BLUETOOTH` & `TRANSPORT_VPN`)
using [`registerNetworkCallback`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#registerNetworkCallback(android.net.NetworkRequest,%20android.net.ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback)).